# Power Query can't find files in folder

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am trying to import files from my Downloads folder using Power Query.  I have done this many times before without issue.  When I try now, all of the folders are empty when I try using the "from folder" option.  It recognizes the files and will import them individually but not when I try to import the folder.  All suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, questions without the code are the best.

Comment: First suggestion is to post the code you are using!

Comment: I would love to be able to post the code but there is no code to post.  When I click on Get Data > From File > From Folder, there are no files available in any folder.  When I click on Get Data > From File > From Workbook, all of my files are available and I can import them individually.  I'm trying to import and combine multiple files from the folder and appreciate any feedback that anyone has as to why Excel doesn't recognize the files when I try the "From Folder" option but they are there to import individually.

Comment: Sounds like a system specific issue.

Comment: That's why I posted it here hoping that someone else has run into a similar issue and has feedback on what they did to correct it.  If there is a better place to post questions in regards to settings or permissions that may solve my problem, that would be helpful as well.